# Why do some of my pages return 500s on my XAMPP server?

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I cannot figure out what the  hell is going on for the life of me.

Normally when I want to run a site locally for testing purposes, I simply point my browser to:

http://localhost/site_folder

This works on the majority of my pages but for some strange (and I mean really strange) reason, some folders give a 500 redirect error.

I thought perhaps something was wrong with one of my scripts until I created a new folder and a basic php info page:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

my site comes up with:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, postmaster@localhost
>   and inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server
>   Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to
>   handle the request.
>
> Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) DAV/2
>   mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l
>   mod_autoindex_color PHP/5.3.1
>   mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1
>   mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 Server at
>   localhost Port 80

I check my local error logs and get:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Nothing has changed on my configuration, no .htaccess files to mess with, other folders work. WTF is going on?

Comment: look at your access log and see where it is redirecting to and from.

Comment: access_log shows no issues: 127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2010:15:35:52 -0500] "GET /balls/phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 500 865 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3"
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Oct/2010:15:35:52 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 865 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have dealt with this problem before and it was the result of a hidden .htaccess file, I know you said you have checked for one but possibly try checking your htdocs folder because if you documentroot is set to /htdocs in your httpd.conf then any folders inside that will inherit your .htaccess setup.

It's probably not the case but just worth giving it a check anyway.

Comment: this was it - hidden .htaccess file in the htdocs folder caused the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience i find that XAMPP is awful piece of software. I always build my environment from scratch, its not as hard as people think. Its very difficult to diagnose errors with somebody else's setup such as XAMPP.

Most likely this is where your redirect issue comes from. I would check all php keeping note of any redirects and stay away from any code that is run by XAMPP (disabling any pages that come with it).

Hopefully this should help, but my final advice is get rid of it =)

Comment: doesn't diagnose the problem or help my issue. Scrapping a local system (which DOES work on some of my sites) is extremely unreasonable

Comment: JM4, Unless you post httpd.conf, php.ini and syslog with debug set to a reasonable level **noone** will be able to debug your problem

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's too late to answer but the error that happened to me was the following

```
Rewrite Engine On
RewriteCond % { REQUEST_FILENAME }! -f
RewriteRule ^ ([ ^ \.] + ) $ $1.php[NC, L]
RewriteRule ^ ([ ^ \.] + ) $ $1.html[NC, L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://pagina.com/404
    Error Document 500 http://pagina.com/404
```

The .htaccess was misconfigured, using VS it throws me it wraps the file with spaces
Just remove the .htaccess in test and in production you put it