# Finding what is causing internal server 500 error

Tags: apache, xampp, internal-server-error, error-logging

I am backing up my clients PrestaShop website on my localhost Xampp machine. I am receiving a internal server 500 error, but I have no idea what might be causing it. The website works live on my client's server. My Xampp error log also does not give me any errors.

How do I find what is causing this internal server 500 error?

Comment: Does information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3945966/62576) help at all? How about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7237638/htaccess-causing-server-error-500?rq=1)?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It can't be an htaccess error because I am using Prestashop's untouched file. There are no hidden files...